# Auto complete doesn't work with SQL Server CE password protected database

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

When I add password to my SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 database, the auto complete function for the textbox stops working (although I can connect normally to the database with the application.. Namely the connection is functioning properly).

All the settings are the same as I did only add the password to the connection string.

**Working auto complete**:

```
SqlCeConnection sqlcon = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = TranslationTest.sdf");
SqlCeCommand sqlcmd;
SqlCeDataReader sqldr;
AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
        sqlcon.Open();
        sqlcmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT EnglishWord,ArabicWord FROM T1", sqlcon);
        sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
        AutoCompleteStringCollection mycollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        while (sqldr.Read())
        {  
              mycollection.Add(sqldr.GetString(0));         
        }

        textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = mycollection;
        sqlcon.Close(); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {   
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);    
    }
}
```

*Not working (with password)*:

```
SqlCeConnection sqlcon = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = TranslationTest.sdf;Password=778899;");
SqlCeCommand sqlcmd;
SqlCeDataReader sqldr;

AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
        sqlcon.Open();
        sqlcmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT EnglishWord,ArabicWord FROM T1", sqlcon);
        sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();

        AutoCompleteStringCollection mycollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        while (sqldr.Read())
        {    
            mycollection.Add(sqldr.GetString(0));         
        }

        textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = mycollection;
        sqlcon.Close();  
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {   
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);    
    }
}
```

Extras :

- Multiline = false
- Auto complete mode = suggest (tried Suggest & append .. the same problem)
- Password added with VS2010 https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEKMp.jpg

Comment: Any errors - you cannot simply add a password to an existind db, you need to Compact with new connectionstring with password.

Comment: @ErikEJ , no sir you got me wrong. I mean when I use another database which is password protected. So it's fully functioning in everything else except for auto complete the text-box text as it stops suggesting results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been introduced with some conflicts in the code itself and finally it turns out that I've conflicts in the database "DATASET" that is automatically added to the project each time I try to add or modify database which messed things up.

Now I've just deleted everything and started all over again with password protected database and it's functioning properly (I mean the auto complete function).

Hope this helps anyone who might face the same problem in the future